# Using Input Class in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I retrieve an URL like below

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/?first=value_on_first_param&second=value_on_second_param
```

And at that URL I have code to retrieve the URL that has some GET parameters on URL

```
if( $first = $this->input->get( 'first' )
    && $second = $this->input->get( 'second' )
){

    echo 'first param: '.$first;
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'second param: '.$second;

}
```

Then I try to print the output of params that assigned to some variables

```
first param: 1
second param: value_on_second_param
```

As we see above, I have first param value to be 1 not value_on_first_param. Why? Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the assignment:

You do

```
$first = 
       $this->input->get( 'first' ) && 
$second = $this->input->get( 'second' )
```

is like

```
$first = 
      ( $this->input->get( 'first' ) && 
        $second = $this->input->get( 'second' )
      )
```

so the `$first` will get true value.

You have to use it:

```
if( ($first = $this->input->get( 'first' ))
    && ($second = $this->input->get( 'second' ) )
){

    echo 'first param: '.$first;
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'second param: '.$second;

}
```

Comment: I see. If I'm not mistaken, operator `=` has lower precedence than `&&`, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, you're right. The `&&` has higher precedence than `=` but if you use `AND` the result will be as expected because `=` higher than `AND`

Comment: You can see complete list of PHP precedence here http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php.